# Searching PubMed using BioPython and writing to CSV

Tags: python, csv, pubmed

I am using BioPython to fill a CSV file of data about citations from their PubMed title. I have written this so far:

```
import csv
from Bio import Entrez
import bs4

Entrez.email = "my_email"
CSVfile = open('srData.csv')
fileReader = csv.reader(CSVfile)
Data = list(fileReader)

with open('blank.csv','w') as f1:
  writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
  for id in Data:
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=id, rettype="gb", retmode="xml")
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    title=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']
    abstract=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']
    mesh =record[0]['MedlineCitation']['MeshHeadingList']
    descriptors = ','.join(term['DescriptorName'] for term in mesh)
    writer.writerow([title, abstract, descriptors])
```

However, this produces an unusual output where the title, abstract and MeSH terms are spread across multiple columns and not separated which I presume is due to their type. (). I wish my csv table to be made of three columns, one containing title, the other the abstract and the other the mesh terms.

How can I accomplish this?

Sample Output

To clarify, the first column contains the entire title, and the beginning of the abstract and the next few columns contain subsequent portions of the abstract. I require them split, into distinct columns. ie. The first column should only contain the title. The seccond only the abstract, the third only MeSH terms.

Currently, the first column contains:

```
"Distinct and combined vascular effects of ACE blockade and HMG-CoA reductase inhibition in hypertensive subjects.  {u'AbstractText': ['Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with elevated sympathetic activity. Both are independent cardiovascular risk factors and both affect endothelium-mediated vasodilation. To identify the effects of cholesterol-lowering and antihypertensive treatments on vascular reactivity and vasodilative capacity"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the title, abstract and MeSH terms are spread across multiple columns"? Can you show us some sample output?

Comment: @Iarsks Have done so.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']` is a dictionary that contains the abstract text and a shorter summary.  If you want the actual abstract, instead of:

```
abstract=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']
```

You need:

```
abstract=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText'][0]
```

Now `abstract` contains a single string and should be suitable for writing to your CSV file.

**Update**

I'm unable to reproduce the error you've described in your comment, even when using the same input data:

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> Entrez.email = '...'
>>> id=10067800
>>> handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=id, rettype="gb", retmode="xml")
>>> record = Entrez.read(handle)
>>> abstract=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText'][0]
>>> abstract
StringElement('To assess the antihypertensive efficacy and safety of the novel AT1 receptor antagonist, telmisartan, compared with that of enalapril in elderly patients with mild to moderate hypertension.', attributes={u'NlmCategory': u'OBJECTIVE', u'Label': u'OBJECTIVE'})
>>>
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/csvPubMed.py", line 16, in <module>
    abstract=record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText']
KeyError: 'Abstract'

Comment: That error doesn't make any sense, because the path `record[0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']` is what you're *already* using in your code.  If the code you posted in your question runs without error, you shouldn't be seeing that error with my code (although it is conceivable you would see an error concerning `AbstractText` if your data is different from what I was using).

Comment: The first column still contains parts of the abstract.

Comment: The error was occurring because I was attempting to query data using this from this citation: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=10067800&report=xml&format=text. Any ideas for a way to manage this exception?